# bootstrapping WCF for multiple bindings

Tags: wcf, dependency-injection, named-pipes

I used to have a HTTP based transport and I bootstrapped my app in Applicaiton_Start.
By bootstrap I mean set up my DI container etc.
I want to change to named pipes but I may want to continue using HTTP on another server.

Can I use the following to bootstrap independent of transport?
I'm hosting inside IIS.

```
/// <summary>
/// This class needs to reside in the App_Code special ASP.NET folder
/// It also needs to be set with a build action of Content
/// The signature public static void AppInitialize() is recognised by ASP.NET and is 
/// always called no matter the binding (HTTP or not)
/// </summary>
public static class AppStart
{
    public static void AppInitialize()
    {
        Bootstrapper.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a custom [ServiceHostFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.activation.servicehostfactory.aspx) along with several other classes.

Rory Primrose has two good blog posts on the topic using Unity.

- [Unity dependency injection for WCF services – Part 1](http://www.neovolve.com/2010/05/15/unity-dependency-injection-for-wcf-services-e28093-part-1/)
- [Unity dependency injections for WCF services – Part 2](http://www.neovolve.com/2010/05/17/unity-dependency-injections-for-wcf-services-e28093-part-2/)

Comment: Pages have been removed.

Comment: @Th3B0Y Fixed broken links